# How to plot the frequency of a categorical variable according to a quantitative variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, dplyr, frequency

I need your help for a small problem. For a master's project, I need to plot the frequency of a behavior in a bird species according to the age in days.
Unfortunately I can't provide all the data because it's confidential but I can give you the example I'm trying to make:

- I have 7 different type of behaviors: Active, Feeding, etc...
- I have a pool of individuals which were tagged and I have data for ages ranging from 0 to 1500 days (according to the tagging date).

What I need to do is see if for a given age, a behavior will be more frequent, and plot it.

I've tried several different methods, like this one I found in the site:
First I tried to calculate the frequency of behaviors for every age:

```
 df %>%
 group_by(agesincetaggingdays, behaviors) %>%
 summarise(n = n()) %>%
 mutate(freq = n / sum(n))
```

This gave me:

```
 agesincetaggingdays behaviors     n     freq
             <dbl> <chr>     <int>    <dbl>
  1                   0 Active        5 0.000410
  2                   0 Feeding      49 0.0724
```

Basically the outpout gives me the frequencies of the behaviors for each age in all individuals.

Now I want to know how I can extract these frequencies and do a plot with it, for each behavior.
I take again my previous example:

If I want to see how active the birds are according to their age, I would have to extract all the frequencies of the Active behavior  across all ages and then plot on the y axis the frequency of the behavior and on the x axis the age.

Is there a way how to do that ? Don't hesitate if you want more precision.

Thank you !

Comment: maybe you can provide a sample data. either just a sample from your data or you make a sample so we can work out the shape of the data we are working on directly. Based on the description, it looks like something you could do with `geom_bar()` and `facet_grid()` from `ggplot2` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to extract anything, if I understand you correctly - the code you used already gives you a dataframe which can be passed to `ggplot()` to make a plot.

I created some dummy data to illustrate the workflow. Of course you might want to choose a plot type that suits your needs (I used a stacked area chart below).

```r
library(tidyverse)

# create sample data
df <- tibble(
  behavior = sample(letters[1:5], size = 1e6, replace = TRUE),
  age = sample(0:1500, size = 1e6, replace = TRUE)
)

# compute shares
df <- df |> 
  count(age, behavior) |> 
  mutate(share = n / sum(n),
         .by = age)

# plot
ggplot(df) +
  geom_area(aes(age, share, fill = behavior))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I think I know what I was doing wrong. Let me explain.

Basically I had something like i showed you:

```
    a <- df %>%
  group_by(agesincetaggingdays, behaviors) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n))
```

My Output:

```
    agesincetaggingdays behaviors     n     freq
             <dbl> <chr>     <int>    <dbl>
  1                   0 Active        5 0.000410
  2                   0 Feeding      49 0.0724
```

Then, I wanted to "extract" the frequency for plotting, because doing counts would not be very useful since some individuals were not recorded anymore.
What I did was:

```
Activefreq <- a %>% filter(behaviors == "Active")
```

etc... for each behaviors, and then I just plotted it using simple abline function:

```
ggplot(data = Activefreq, aes(x = agesincetaggingdays, y = freq)) + geom_line()
```

Sorry, I think I just messed things up and I finally got to understand things by myself. But thanks for the help though !